# Linux: error while loading shared libraries: libQtSvg.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, dependencies

I had an error when trying to run Vaa3D:

`error while loading shared libraries: libQtSvg.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have a bunch of Qt libraries installed, but I don't see one called `libqtsvg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the package is `libqt4-svg`. On Ubuntu: `sudo apt install libqt4-svg`

Answer (score 2):

For **qt5** the package is called `libqt5svg5`

Ubuntu 19.10: `sudo apt install libqt5svg5`